# Kentico Macros inside macro

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

I'm trying to set the style tag inside an email widget in macros. Following works fine

```
style="background-color: {% CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["Keyton.EmailTemplateUIElements"].Items.Where("StyleKey = 'theme_bg_1'").FirstItem.StyleValue #%};"
```

Now, I want to change the above query to use multiple where clauses. The value of the second where clause (Theme) is coming from a property in the widget. I tried the following query but the syntax doesn't seem to be right.

```
style="background-color: {% CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["Keyton.EmailTemplateUIElements"].Items.Where("StyleKey = 'theme_bg_1' and Theme = {% Theme %} ").FirstItem.StyleValue #%};"
```

[image]

How do I set the second parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to concatenate the second variable instead of escaping it. In your .Where() try:

```
{% CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.CustomTables["Keyton.EmailTemplateUIElements"].Items.Where("StyleKey = 'theme_bg_1' and Theme = '"+ Theme +"'").FirstItem.StyleValue #%}
```

Assuming Theme is a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to abandon trying to write such a complicated and poor performing macro statement and instead write a custom macro method. With that you can use normal C# syntax and kenticos APIs as well as leverage CacheHelper to cache data to prevent performance issues.